# How to Print GitLab Merge Request id while building in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

i have created a freestyle job in Jenkins to build Merge Request that are created in GitLab.

**During build not able to print merge request id**

following are the configurations i done in freestyle job

`Refspec has +refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*`

`Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') origin/merge-requests/*`

in execute shell i have added variables as follows which is mentioned gitlab-plugin   `https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables`

`echo ${gitlabMergeRequestId}`

`echo ${gitlabMergeRequestIid}`

During build i am not able to print merge request id, how can i configure jenkins job to build merge request id during jenkins build?

Comment: You can use the gitlab api to return the merge request id and capture it in a variable, then you can print the variable. Here is the API for the same https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-project-merge-requests

For this you need the project id of the gitlab project.

Comment: assuming the build is triigerd by a mergeRequest event from GitLab(webhook), try - echo "${env.gitlabMergeRequestIid}"

Comment: @PankajSaini i am trying using Jenkins free style job, if you have declarative pipeline script for building merge request please share

Answer (score 0):

First, in Jenkins, create a Job of type **Pipeline**

[image: Pipeline Job]

Access the job's configuration area and adjust settings according to your needs, but pay special attention to the *GitLab Connection* and *Build Triggers* settings. Usually I only select *Opened Merge Request Events*, but you can tune it as you'd like.

As we use a Global Library with the pipeline source codes, we solely indicate the name of the pipeline in the *Pipeline Scrip* section, but here you can insert the whole code of the pipeline you'd like to execute.

Here's and example:

```
  pipeline {
    agent { label 'maven' }
    options {
      buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '20', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '20'))
      gitlabBuilds(builds: ['Merge', 'Init', 'Build', 'Unit Test', 'Integration Test', 'SQ Analysis', 'SQ Gate'])
    }
    stages {
      stage('Merge') {
        steps {
          script {
            gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'Merge') {
              def gitHelper = new GitHelper()
              gitHelper.merge()
            }
          }
        }
      }
      stage('Init') {
        steps {
          script {
            gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'Init') {
              init()
              def buildHelper = new BuildHelper()
              config = buildHelper.jenkinsFileParams()
              downloadConfig config.configBranch
            }
          }
        }
      }
      stage('Build') {
        steps {
          gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'Build') {
            mvn 'compile -U dependency:copy-dependencies'
          }
        }
      }
      stage('Unit Test') {
        steps {
          gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'Unit Test') {
            mvn "test -Dspring.profiles.active=${env.SPRING_TEST_PROFILE} \
              -Dspring.config.location=./${env.CONFIG_REPO}/${env.ARTIFACT_ID}/ \
              -DLOGGING_CONFIG_LOCATION=./${env.CONFIG_REPO}/${env.ARTIFACT_ID}"
          }
        }
      }
      stage('Integration Test') {
        steps {
          gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'Integration Test') {
            mvn "integration-test -Pintegration \
              -Dspring.profiles.active=${env.SPRING_INTEGRATION_PROFILE} \
              -Dspring.config.location=./${env.CONFIG_REPO}/${env.ARTIFACT_ID}/ \
              -DLOGGING_CONFIG_LOCATION=./${env.CONFIG_REPO}/${env.ARTIFACT_ID}"
          }
        }
      }
      stage('SQ Analysis') {
        steps {
          gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'SQ Analysis') {
            sonarScanner()
          }
        }
      }
      stage('SQ Gate') {
        steps {
          gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'SQ Gate') {
            sonarGate()
          }
        }
      }
    }
    post {
      always {
        sendMail()
      }
    }
  }
```

The `merge` stage relies upon a method inside a helper class looking like this:

```
void merge() {
  setJenkinsGitInfo()
  env.BRANCH_NAME = env.gitlabSourceBranch
  env.GIT_COMMIT = env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit

  checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: [
      $class                           : 'GitSCM',
      branches                         : [
          [name: "origin/${env.gitlabSourceBranch}"]
      ],
      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
      extensions                       : [
          [
              $class : 'PreBuildMerge',
              options: [
                  fastForwardMode: 'FF',
                  mergeRemote    : 'origin',
                  mergeStrategy  : 'DEFAULT',
                  mergeTarget    : env.gitlabTargetBranch
              ]
          ]
      ],
      submoduleCfg                     : [],
      userRemoteConfigs                : [
          [
              credentialsId: GITLAB_SSH_CREDENTIALS,
              name         : 'origin',
              url          : env.gitlabSourceRepoSshUrl
          ]
      ]
  ]
}
```

The last step is going to Gitlab and creating a webhook for merge requests and notes/comments events, pointing to the job you created.

For instance: `http://jenkins.url/project/springboot-merge-request/`